# How do you use the same parameter on multiple fields?

Tags: ms-access

I'd like to use the same parameter on multiple fields because I'm pulling half of my data from Access and half of my data from SQL Server. The SQL Server table is mostly a clone of the Access table. All the new data goes into SQL Server but the users still interface with everything through Access (via an ODBC Data Source).

There are some old queries that I'm trying to make work seamlessly with the new SQL Server table. Basically they look like this:

```
SELECT [AccessCoolUsersTable].Name AS Name, [AccessCoolUsersTable].FavoriteSandwhich AS Sandwhich
FROM [AccessCoolUsersTable]
WHERE [AccessCoolUsersTable].FavoriteSandwhich = [Enter a Sandwhich]
```

And I want them to function like this (this is pseudo-code)

```
SELECT [AccessCoolUsersTable].Name As Name, [AccessCoolUsersTable].FavoriteSandwhich AS Sandwhich
FROM [AccessCoolUsersTable]
UNION
SELECT [SQLCoolUsersTable].Name As Name, [SLCoolUsersTable].FavoriteSandwhich AS Sandwhich
FROM [SQLCoolUsersTable]
WHERE 
    [AccessCoolUsersTable].FavoriteSandwhich = [Enter a Sandwhich]
    OR
    [SQLCoolUsersTable].FavoriteSandwhich = [Enter a Sandwhich]
```

But what happens is it first prompts for "Enter Parameter Value `[AccessCoolUsersTable].FavoriteSandwhich`" and then prompts for "Enter Parameter Value `Enter a Sandwhich`".

Ijust want it to ask for the value once and use it for both `[AccessCoolUsersTable].FavoriteSandwhich` and `[SQLCoolUsersTable]`. Is that possible?

Comment: Since Access interprets `[AccessCoolUsersTable].FavoriteSandwhich` to be a parameter, double-check the spelling of that name.  `FavoriteSandwhich` or `FavoriteSandwich`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `WHERE` clause needs to be on the individual queries in your `UNION' query. Also you need to define the parameter in the query.

```
PARAMETERS [Enter a Sandwhich] Text ( 255 );
SELECT [AccessCoolUsersTable].Name As Name, [AccessCoolUsersTable].FavoriteSandwhich AS Sandwhich
FROM [AccessCoolUsersTable]
WHERE [AccessCoolUsersTable].FavoriteSandwhich = [Enter a Sandwhich]
UNION
SELECT [SQLCoolUsersTable].Name As Name, [SLCoolUsersTable].FavoriteSandwhich AS Sandwhich
FROM [SQLCoolUsersTable]
WHERE [SQLCoolUsersTable].FavoriteSandwhich = [Enter a Sandwhich]
```

OR using the union as a sub query

```
PARAMETERS [Enter a Sandwhich] Text ( 255 );
SELECT a.Name, a.FavoriteSandwhich FROM
(SELECT [AccessCoolUsersTable].Name As Name, [AccessCoolUsersTable].FavoriteSandwhich AS Sandwhich
FROM [AccessCoolUsersTable]
UNION
SELECT [SQLCoolUsersTable].Name As Name, [SLCoolUsersTable].FavoriteSandwhich AS Sandwhich
FROM [SQLCoolUsersTable]) 
AS a
WHERE a.FavoriteSandwhich = [Enter a Sandwhich]
```

the first query will have a better performance, since the results are first filtered with the `WHERE` then added to the `UNION`